# Почему в Opera не работают media запросы?

Tags: css, media-queries, less

Версия Opera: 56.0.3051.116

Проблема в том, что media-запрос отрабатывает в FireFox и в Chrome, но не работает в Opera, не знаю с чем может быть связано.

Код Less:

```css
.background-wave {
    width: 55%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #00a8ff;
    z-index: 1;

    &--active {
        width: 30%;
    }

    &__item {
        background-color: #00a8ff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0;
        width: 100vh;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        z-index: 10;
        transition: 1s;

        &--active {
            transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(50%);
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1610px) {
            transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(40%);
        }
    }

}
```

Код запроса на выходе получается таким:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1610px) {
    .background-wave__item {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(40%);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(40%);
        transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(40%)
    }
}
```

Comment: там Вы покажите, какой у Вас на выходе css получается

Comment: @humster_spb, отредактировал вопрос

Comment: ну, я вижу, что для Оперы вендорного префикса нет - может быть, в этом проблема